# Three.js - How the functions of object3D.children can be accessed?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use line like this

```
myObject3D.children.forEach( 
    function(pChild){ 
         return pChild.position.multiplyScalar(myMultiplier) 
    } 
);
```

and this

```
myObject3D.children.forEach( 
    function(pChild){ 
         pChild.position.copy(myVector3) 
    } 
);
```

But for some reasons, functions in child elements of 'myObject3D' seems to be inexistent. (`"Uncaught TypeError: pChild.position.multiplyScalar is not a function"`)

However, elements in 'myObject3D' are 'Mesh' objects.

Can anybody suggest what can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `forEach` callback shouldn't return anything.

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your second code segment.

The code below runs without errors.

```js
var group = new THREE.Object3D();
var geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red"
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);

group.add(mesh);
group.add(mesh.clone());
group.add(mesh.clone());
group.add(mesh.clone());
group.add(mesh.clone());

var myVector3 = new THREE.Vector3();

group.children.forEach(function(pChild) {
  pChild.position.multiplyScalar(5);
  pChild.position.copy(myVector3)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.js"></script>
```

Please verify that you're populating your group with the correct kinds of objects. Also, you can always test if a function is available before using it:

```
if(obj.someFunction){
    obj.someFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Finally, the problem was my group itself. "myObject3D" was stored in an array, I fixed that and it works :)